# beautifulsoup won't recognize lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm attempting to use `lxml` as the parser for BeautifulSoup because the default one is MUCH slower, however i'm getting this error:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
  File "/home/rob/python/stock/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled lxml as well as beautifulsoup many times, however it still will not read it. I've tried reinstalled lxml dependencies as well and i'm still getting this.

I even made a new virtual environment and installed fresh everything and still get this error.

Anyone have any idea whats going on here?

**Edits**

Using latest versions of bs4 and lxml on Python 2.7.x on ubuntu desktop

i can `import lxml` but i cannot `from lxml import etree` that is returning:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /home/rob/python/stock/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so)
```

i have libxml however i'm not sure the version, but i installed and reinstalled the latest. also tried to manually install 2.9.0 and still nothing

Comment: I'm assuming you have the latest versions of bs4 and lxml, and a reasonably recent Python 2.7.x, right? (Might as well edit the version numbers into your question anyway.)

Comment: Also, have you tested `lxml` on its own to make sure it's working?

Comment: Does `site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py` exist?

Comment: @abarnert yes.. added to questions

Comment: @unutbu yes. i think it may be lxml thats not working, check the error i just added to the bottom

Answer (score 7):

It looks like lxml has not been successfully installed. To install `lxml` on Ubuntu, run

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2
```

In virtualenv:

```
pip install --upgrade lxml
pip install cssselect
```

Comment: i've uninstalled and reinstalled lxml at least 20 times. still nothing. also tried installing dependencies and it says they are all already installed

Comment: It might help to uninstall and reinstall lxml one more time, and post the commands you're using.

Comment: just did `pip uninstall lxml` -> `pip install --upgrade lxml` which returned `Successfully installed lxml
Cleaning up...` and still getting the same error

Comment: How was libxml2 installed? Mine, on Ubuntu is in `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2`. For some reason yours is looking for it in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2`.

Comment: Not sure. how can i uninstall and reinstall it? I'm able to use lxml OFF virtualenv, but its giving the error only in virtualenv's. so confused

Comment: Is your virtualenv directory `/home/rob/python/stock`? If so, does `/home/rob/python/stock/bin/pip` exist? With `virtualenv` activated, what does `which pip` return?

Answer (score 1):

Go to these pages:

1. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect
2. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.2.5

download the source files for both packages. Expand each of them into a different folder. Then in each folder locate the setup.py file and run the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

You may run into some problems with lxml. If you get an error like

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

make sure you install libxml2-dev & libxslt1-dev using

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Hopefully that should work.