# Error while install lxml

Tags: python, macos, lxml

I'm trying to install lxml with pip. I received this initial error when running my script:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

A quick search of the above error (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322948/beautifulsoup-wont-recognize-lxml)) revealed I need to install lxml.

While trying to install lxml I receive the following error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Xcode 5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc5_release_notes.html):

> The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified.
>
> ...
>
> To workaround this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the error to a warning. For example, you can install a Python native extension with:
>
> ```
> $ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future \
>   easy_install ExtensionName
> ```

Set following environment variable before installing `lxml`:

```
export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
```